# Pushing responses of axios request into array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have been pounding my head against this problem, and need help with a solution. I have an array of IDs within a JSON, and I am iterating over that array and making a GET request of each ID. I want to then push the response of those GET requests into an array.

Here is the function I am using to push the registrations into the array. It is iterating through an array of IDs:

```
getRegistrations = async (event) => {
    let registrations = [];

    await event.registrations.forEach(registration => axios.get('/event/getRegistration', {
        params: {
            id: registration
        }
    }).then(res => {
            registrations.push(res.data.properties)
        }
    ).catch(err => console.log(err)));
    return registrations;
};
```

Here is where I am calling that code:

```
render() {
    let event = this.getEvent();
    let registrations2 = [{
        age: 19,
        bio: 'test',
        firstName: 'hello',
        lastName: 'bye',
        password: 'adadas',
        telephone: "4920210213"
    }];
    if (this.props.listOfEvents.events.length !== 0 && !this.props.listOfEvents.gettingList && event) { //check if the array is empty and list has not been rendered yet
        let columns = [];
        let registrations = this.getRegistrations(event);
        console.log(registrations);
        let eventProperties = event.properties[0];
        Object.keys(eventProperties).forEach(key => columns.push({
            title: eventProperties[key].title,
            dataIndex: key,
            key: key
        }));
        console.log(registrations);
        console.log(registrations2);
        return (
            <h1>hi</h1>
        )
    }
    return <Loading/>
}
```

When I console-log 'registrations' vs 'registrations2' they should be very identical. However, in the javascript console on Google Chrome, 'registrations appears as '[]' where 'registrations2' appears as '[{...}]'.

I know that it is an issue related to promises (I am returning the registrations array before actually pushing) but I have no idea how to fix it! Some friendly help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Seeing the `getRegistrations()` is async, you will need to account for that when invoking it. Consider this:
`this.getRegistrations(event).then((registrations) => {
console.log('got data', registrations);
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend `Promise.all`, it will resolve single Promise after all promises have resolved. And technically async function is also promise so it will return promise.

here  the example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jzz1ko5l73?fontsize=14

Comment: This is the first thing to actually work! How can I access the data outside the `console.log(data)`? I need to be able to use those registrations to show their data in a table.

Comment: are you familiar with react state. you can use state in this situation

Comment: I did that, and it worked! However, I should avoid calling setState in render, correct? Would it be better to refactor this code to be called in componentDidMount?

Comment: yes you should deal api call in componentDidMount, if you want I will update the sandbox code for you.

Comment: that would be amazing! Also, here is my code for `this.getEvent()`: `return this.props.listOfEvents.events.find(event => event._id === this.props.match.params.eventId);` I think that this is working asynchronously as it is sometimes undefined. Is that true? How can I fix that as well? Thank you so much, you are a lifesaver!

Comment: You are a lifesaver! StackOverflow needs more people like you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `componentDidMount()`lifecycle method for proper execution and state to store the data.

```
constructor (props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {registrations :[]}
}
componentDidMount () {
    let response = this.getRegistrations()
    this.setState({registrations : response});
}
```

Then access that state in render method. It's not good practice to call api from render mothod.

Answer (score 0):

Since `getRegistrations(event)` returns a promise, you should perform operations on its return value inside `then`.

Instead of

```
let registrations = this.getRegistrations(event);
console.log(registrations);
```

Do this

```
this.getRegistrations(event).then(registrations => {
  console.log(registrations);
  // other operations on registrations
});
```

Comment: Is getRegistrations returning a promise? Wouldn't it be technically be returning the array? Also, when I try and do something like `console.log(registrations[0])` it logs `undefined`. Yet `console.log(registrations)` looks like the array is perfectly valid in the Javascript console?

Comment: async function returns a Promise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function